# I need explaination about Develop Detailed Table Schematics In Step 4, Chapter 20, The Data Warehouse Toolkit, 3rd Edition

Tags: etl

Have anyone read The Data Warehouse Toolkit, 3rd Edition written by Ralph Kimball and his colleagues? I signed up for a Data Warehouse course at my uni and my prof told me and my group to read Chapter 20 and summaries to him.

I've struggled to understand this schematic:
[image]

**Can somebody give me a visual presentation of the DMR Extract, Usage1, Usage2, Fact_stage1, Fact_stage2, Fact_stage3, Fact_stage4 and Electric_Usage_Fact?**